# Choppy video playback 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video, vlc, mplayer, playback

I just installed 11.10 and I also installed the ATI prop. driver. Whenever I try to play a mkv file in mplayer, smplayer, or vlc, it is choppy. And in the case of VLC the audio is messed up also. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Try to see if my answer works for you. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/94478/1080p-choppy-on-two-different-gpus-what-else-could-it-be/96177#96177

Comment: Which driver are you using for ATI?

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing the driver from the ati website (if you haven't done so already). Follow these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Answer (score 0):

You need to install xvba-va driver and then enable GPU acceleration in VLC codecs.